# using aws reachability analyzer for VPC Endpoint Gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am attempting to use a VPC Endpoint Gateway to route traffic from an RDS network interface to S3 via the VPC Endpoint Gateway; therefore keeping all traffic within the VPC.

However, I just can't seem to connect! I have even followed the instructions in [*What can I check if my VPC route tables are not working?*](https://youtu.be/U4TDYrpcimE).

1. There exists a route to the S3 Prefix list and its destination is set to the VPC Endpoint Gateway.
2. The Endpoint policy allows everything as in the demo.

I have even created a Reachability Analyzer from the RDS Network interface to the VPC Endpoint Gateway.

I receive some error messages from the analyzer, but can not understand how to correct them:

> A. Route from `$prefix-list` to gatewayId, in route table `$route-table`, cannot transmit the packet because the packet's destination address does not match `$prefix-list`.

> B. VPC gateway endpoint `$vpc-gateway-endpoint` can only send traffic with source addresses within prefix list `$prefix-list`.

My hypothesis here is that I need to be able to set a "destination" IP address that matches the `$prefix-list`, but am not clear how that can be done with the reachability analyzer. It doesn't seem possible to try destinations to arbitrary IPs using the analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

There does seem to be an issue with Reachability Analyzer when you set the destination to a gateway endpoint for S3. I encountered the same error when I tried to diagnose a connectivity issue between a Network Interface for Lambda in a private subnet and S3: it selected a private IP address within the VPC as the destination, not an address within the prefix list for S3.

> It doesn't seem possible to try destinations to arbitrary IPs using the analyzer.

Thankfully, this is actually possible:

> [image: Choosing IP Address as the destinationtype]

I turned on VPC flow logs to capture REJECTed packets and was able to see which IP addresses the source was trying to reach:

[image: CloudWatch Logs Insights flow log result]

<sup>From CloudWatch Logs Insights</sup>

I probably could've picked an IP address from the prefix list's CIDR blocks instead of going through that trouble, but anyway, creating a new Reachability Analyzer path with this IP address as the destination revealed some actual configuration issues. In my case, these were

- Security Group for the connection source did not have an outbound rule for the prefix list
- ACL of the subnet of the connection source did not allow outbound connection to IP addresses in the prefix list

These are both explained in AWS's KB article "[Why can't I connect to an S3 bucket using a gateway VPC endpoint?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint)", which I'd reviewed before, but I hadn't understood clearly that using a gateway endpoint means that the destination address is going to be a public IP address and I need to set up rules accordingly.

Comment: VPC Reachability Analyzer is indeed allowed to select an arbitrary address when this is not configured in the initial request. This can result in the Private IP of the VPC Endpoint ENI to be chosen. Indeed using an IP Address from the S3 Prefix List is a suitable choice for the diagnosis you have in mind. Thank you for answering this question so thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

For me in a similar pincn it turns out the Analyser doesnt return the actual cause. It was a NACL that didnt allow traffic the the public IPs needed for AWS Gateway Endpoints. I fixed this and it worked fine, even though the Analyser said the NACL was fine.